# Преобразовать json в формат

Tags: javascript, json

Имеется json

```
{
"Car": {
    "Pos": ["id", "mark"],
    "Bat": [
        [1, "bmw"]
    ]
},
"Temp": {
    "Pos": ["min", "hig", "mid"],
    "Bat": [[1, 2, 3]
   }
}
```

Как его преобразовать в формат

```
{
"Car":{
"id": 1,
"mark": bmw
},
"Temp": {
"min": 1,
"hig": 2,
"mid": 3
}
}
```

Comment: Приведённый вами второй пример JSON-а весь в ошибках

Comment: Если выходной формат тоже json, то финальные запятые не нужны (это ошибка в json): например, после bmw в **"mark": bmw,**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот такой вариант

```js
const src = {
  "Car": {
    "Pos": ["id", "mark"],
    "Bat": [
        [1, "bmw"],
        [2, "audi"],
        [3, "mercedes"]
    ]
  },
  "Temp": {
    "Pos": ["min", "hig", "mid"],
    "Bat": [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
   }
};

const res = {};

for(const k in src){
  const cnt = src[k].Pos.length;
  for(let i=0; i<src[k].Bat.length; i+=1){
    res[`${k}${i}`] = {};
    for(let j=0; j<cnt; j+=1){
       res[`${k}${i}`][src[k].Pos[j]] =  src[k].Bat[i][j];
    }
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Все супер, спасибо большое!

Comment: а если у меня есть поля "name": "jake", "lastname": "zone", они без ключей Pos и Bat, как их включить в объект?

Comment: после цикла можно написать `res.name = "lastname"; res.lastname = "zone";